# Where should i store thread dependent data within a receiving rabbitListener component in a multithreaded environment?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I'm using the annotation based approach of spring amqp in a multithreaded environment (i have multiple consumers => multiple rabbit listener containers).

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "tasks")
public void receiveMessage(@Payload Task task) {
     // usage of httpClient here with its own httpContext (would be fine)
     // this method gets called from different listenerContainers / threads
}
```

My component which contains the annotated receiveMessage() method needs to do some http calls with the apache http client. Since i'm working with multiple consumers at the same time, this method gets called from different threads and the apache http client documentation says that i should create a httpContext for each thread to be thread safe. Since all threads are calling the same component method i can't put the httpContext into the component.

Is there something like a listener container context for each listener container where i can put the httpClientContext? Or does somebody have an idea how to solve this easy? I thought about ThreadLocal or a central registry for httpContexts but it would be fine if this would be more easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like that provided by the framework; the simplest solution is to store them in something like a `LinkedBlockingQueue` and check one out, use it, and put it back in the queue when you're done (creating one as necessary if the queue is empty).

`ThreadLocal` will work too, but I prefer to use a pool.